Is it possible to call a cloud function from google bigquery user defined function?
I have a simple HTTP trigger gen2 cloud function to return a string value when triggered, like for instance "Hello <name>". It works when I tested it from google cloud SDK shell. When the cloud function is triggered from google Bigquery's user defined function through an external connection, it returns below error instead of the actual string.

Failed to parse the response body returned by cloud function url as a valid JSON string.

cloud function:
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

user defined function:
CREATE FUNCTION PROJECT_ID.DATASET_ID.hello_http() RETURNS STRING
REMOTE WITH CONNECTION PROJECT_ID.LOCATION.CONNECTION_NAME -- bigquery external connections
OPTIONS (
  endpoint = 'ENDPOINT_URL' -- URL of the above function
)

invoked user defined function:
SELECT  `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_ID.hello_http()`

got error

Failed to parse the response body returned by cloud function url as a valid JSON string.


The error message suggests that your function doesn't return a JSON string.  Does it?  I don't see that it returns properly formatted JSON at all.  Maybe start by making it return the empty JSON object {} and go from there.

It's named remote function in BigQuery and yes, as @DougStevenson said, you must return a valid JSON. Here your return only a string/ https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/remote-functions

@DougStevenson Changed the cloud function and UDF to return a JSON object with 'replies" key. This time there was no error invoking the UDF but it keeps running forever.

@DougStevenson after correcting the calls and replies format in cloud function, trigger from UDF to cloud function worked. Thanks for your advice.
